# How to watch a message queue properly

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I have a scenario where I need to 'watch' an Amazon queue. When a message arrives I need to get this message and process it.

Right now this is implemented with a `do/while` and `Thread.Sleep` when no messages is found. It's working but I would like to know if there is a better approach, possibly with a design pattern or something.

The actual code:

```
      do
        {
            try
            {
                var message = _queue.GetMessage();
                if (message == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100000);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                //process message
             }
        } while(true)
```

Comment: Do you have a blocking GetMessage call available?

Comment: @MichaelT you mean thread safe?

Comment: No, I mean a GetMessage call that blocks until it has something available. A non-blocking version returns immediately (likely with null) that there is no message. A blocking one, well, blocks its execution until there is a message for it.

Comment: dont have, im stucked in a abstraction that the team here implemented upon the Amazon library.

Comment: @MichaelT , just for curiosity, do you have a good link explaining the approach of blocking methods?

Comment: Ahh, this is Amazon's message queue.  One component you may be looking for [long polling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html). GetMessage call would have a timeout value. I would suggest reading up on message queues in general as this is a feature of most.

Comment: This call should not have been named `GetMessage()`.  It should be named `TryGetMessage()` to indicate that it will try to get a message, if one is present, and if none is present, it will return `null`.  Calls named `GetMessage()` are *blocking* calls in all systems that I know of.  @ggui *blocking* simply means that once you have called it, it will not return unless it has a message to return.  And presumably it will do this in a way that makes much more sense than waiting for 100 seconds between checks.

Comment: Mike, i totally agree with you. So, the getmessage will run until it get a message. Im curious about the tecnic that in what it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar approach I've take using Amazon SQS, with a few differences to overcome a few potential downsides;

- if a message becomes available just after you check, you'll be
  waiting 100 seconds before taking another peek, which is not
  particularly responsive.
- If many messages arrive in quick
  succession, you may not be able to keep up with them using this same
  thread to process them as retrieve them.
- If an exception occurs,
  you may be thrown out of the loop and no more messages will be
  processed, ever.

None of these things are difficult to overcome though:

- as mentioned in the comments, Long Polling is a (brief) blocking call
  which will return very quickly as soon as a message arrives (or still
  return null if no message arrives within the timeout - which is a
  maximum of 20 seconds.)
- You can retrieve up to 10 messages in a single call, and these can be
  handed off to a thread pool to process them and keep this thread
  looking for more work/messages.
- try/catch within the loop. I'm sure you had this covered already and
  were just providing the outline!